# Connecting to QB 13 with QBSDK 12 gives qb_utils.js error popup

Tags: quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

QB 13.0 Enterprise introduced an issue in our environment that did not exist in QB 12.0.
Using QBSDK 12.0, qbXML version 4.0, Windows Server 2008 R2 and a solution developed in python 2.7.3. QB File Doctor does not report any problems and all XMLs are successfully validated by the QB XML Validator.

I had to go thru this post to resolve the LGB file corruption issue after the upgrade:[Automatic Login Failure](http://community.intuit.com/posts/automatic-login-through-integrated-applications-fails)

I have created a test .Net program to replicate the problem, which occurs at random points between BeginSession and EndSession calls:

```
using QBXMLRP2Lib;
RequestProcessor2 proc = new RequestProcessor2();
proc.OpenConnection2("Test QB", "Test QB", QBXMLRPConnectionType.localQBD);
string ticket = proc.BeginSession("the path to the QB file", QBFileMode.qbFileOpenMultiUser);
proc.EndSession(ticket);
proc.CloseConnection();
```

A "Script Error" dialog box pops up with:
        Line: 46
        Char: 8
        Error: Unspecified error.
        Code: 0
        URL: https://qbinproduct.intuit.com/ipd/common/js/qb_utils.js

And the standard two options whether to continue to run the script or not.
Regardless of what is chosen, QB crashes with:

```
Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
    Application Name: qbw32.exe
    Application Version: 23.0.4005.2305
    Application Timestamp: 50d6cc51
    Fault Module Name: StackHash_5b31
    Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.17725
    Fault Module Timestamp: 4ec49b8f
    Exception Code: c0000374
    Exception Offset: 000ce6c3
    OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.272.7
    Locale ID: 1033
    Additional Information 1: 5b31
    Additional Information 2: 5b3188f7410a3a5d99b8b3c79d62fc31
    Additional Information 3: 38e7
    Additional Information 4: 38e72e11a56a600df179c0b7bdb3159c
```

I'll appreciate any solutions or suggestions.

Comment: I forgot to mention that QB 13 is R5

Comment: This is a known bug in QuickBooks: https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=7&threadid=18941&highlight_key=y&keyword1=script

Comment: Thanks - I was able to get rid of the script popup by following an advice from the post to add `127.0.0.1 qbinproduct.intuit.com` to the hosts file. The QB however is still crashing on the `CloseConnection` call.

Comment: That's a separate known issue, unfortunately. :-/   There's no resolution that I know of, outside of just not calling CloseConnection (leave QuickBooks open when your app is running and don't call it and you should be OK). Intuit knows about this, they just haven't fixed it yet.